# Why this function is not Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Is a function like $H(x) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{ 0}&{x < 0}\\
{ + \infty }&{x = 0}\\
1&{x > 0}
\end{array}} \right.$ Lebesgue integrable on interval $(-1,1)$?

It looks to me that it is integrable because Lebesgue integral is defined as the least upper bound of the area under all simple functions below $f$. However my friend tells me it is not.

Thank you.

Comment: It is integrable. It is equal to a simple measurable function a.e.

Comment: The measurability or integrability of f is unaffected by what f does on any given set of measure 0. Such as the set $\{0\}$. Perhaps your friend says it's not a real-to-real function because $\infty \not \in R$.

Comment: I think it is even Riemann-integrable because it is continuous a.e. and there is only one point of discontinuity. However, I am not sure if a Riemann integral is defined for an extended-real-valued function.

Comment: @TienTruong Riemann Integral is either defined on bounded functions on a closed interval, or boundedness comes as a result. Either way, we also have an open interval, so it would be an improper Riemann integral.

(PS: Note that the argument on my first post depends on the fact that the Lebesgue measure is complete. For a "direct" proof, it suffices to consider the pre-images of the sets $(\alpha, \infty]$, which are $\{0\}$, $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, \infty)$, hence all measurable.)

Comment: @AloizioMacedo: Thanks. I also understand your argument. :D